# Match two Columns and Pick corresponding value with DateTime validation

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, ms-office, vlookup

In Excel, I have a bunch of rows and columns as follows:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bSPH.png]

Columns are marked A to H.

I want to pick the value in B, find it's corresponding value in G and put the value in column E.

The datetime value that matches in G should be the one **that is greater** than the corresponding datetime value in A.

Eg: B2=AMARJABAT corresponding value in column G is at G10 and G10 > A2.

I tried adding this formula in E but it doesn't work as expected. What do I need to change or use VLOOKUP?

```
=INDEX($B$2:$B$388, MATCH(H2,$H$2:$H$344))
```

Added example for more clarity:

I want to populate column "E". For that, match column 'B' value with corresponding column 'H'.

For eg: Look at B2 (AMARJABAT). Search for it in Column 'H', Pick the adjacent datetime which here is G10 and populate this datetime value E2.

Similarly look at B3 (LCHSGFIN). Search for it in Column 'H'. Pick the adjacent datetime which here is G20 and populate this datetime value E3.

and so on.

The datetime value that matches in G should be the one **that is greater** than the corresponding datetime value in A.

Comment: I don't understand what value you want where and under what conditions. Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: I have added example for more clarity.

Comment: What if the value in G isn't greater? Then pick value from A?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Excel 2019+ or Office O365

```
=MINIFS($G$2:$G$100,$H$2:$H$100,B2,$G$2:$G$100,">" & A2)
```

***Edit:*** *Missed a set of parentheses*
If you have an earlier version of Excel, try:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,1/(($H$2:$H$100=B2)*($G$2:$G$100>A2))* $G$2:$G$100,1)
```

Both formulas will return `#NUM!` error if no match found.

Comment: I have 2016. This works so good. However it fails for B14 and instead of returning G23, it gives 00-01-1900 00:00

Not sure why? Probably B14 is a repetition of B5?

Comment: @CuriousDev I cannot reproduce that.  It will return a zero if it is matching returning the contents of a blank cell.  And also if the date is text and not a real date. And it will return `#NUM!` if there is not match at all. I'm guessing there's something about your actual data that is not accounted for.  Are you sure you are using absolute addressing for the three arrays?  Also, what is the result of `=ISNUMBER(A14)`?

Comment: =ISNUMBER(A14) returns TRUE. 
Column A and G are custom formatted - dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm. Strangely only few columns return 00-01-1900 00:00. Rest are ok. Have tried out everything, even doing this on a new sheet. https://i.stack.imgur.com/BW1j2.png

Comment: @CuriousDev In your screenshot, there are no matching dates in Column G that are greater than the date in Column A.  That will also return a `0` which, when formatted as a date, shows what I see in your screenshot.  You did not write what you want to occur if there is not date that meets the criteria.

Comment: B14 has a matching record at G23 and is greater.

Comment: @CuriousDev If you upload an xlsx file that demonstrates the problem, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @CuriousDev When I run the formula on a representation of your data, it returns 0's in different rows (not on 14, though). I suspect an implementation error on your part, but, again, without the worksheet in hand, I am just guessing.

Comment: Sure. Here's the file - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tVKTWIMPaCqdgwPg_p-w5j_Nu4loCqEJ/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=109017657013228924317&rtpof=true&sd=true  (File > Download > .xlsx)

Comment: @CuriousDev  OK there was a missed set of parentheses in the "older Excel" formula.  Edited to be correct. Should work now.  Don't forget to change the range references to encompass your entire ranges and not stop at row 100.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the IF condition inside of a MIN:

```
=MIN( IF(($H$2:$H$344=B14)*($G$2:$G$344>A14),$G$2:$G$344) )
```